# Using malloc, and transferring what's in the allocated memory to a file

Tags: c

so I'm testing out a program that I made and for some reason some things are not working.

**Please note that the code that I typed in the first and second problem *are not related*.**
So although the names for some things are the same, they are not in the same .c file, neither do they #include each other

**First is this: I FIXED IT!**

Second problem is this: I have a for loop that is based on two factors. The first factor affects the value based on the character (reading argv[2]), the second factor affects the value based on how many copies of it self it has. I'm trying to get the data in that for loop into memory, and then from memory to a file.

For some reason, nothing is being transferred into the file.

It looks something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *filename;
    float length, rate, bytesper;
    char *data;

    data = malloc(sizeof(strlen(argv[2]) * length * rate * bytesper);

    if(data == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nMemory could not be allocated.");
        return -1;
    }

    filename = fopen(argv[1], "wb");

    if(filename == NULL)
    {
        printf("File %s was not created", argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; argv[3][i] != '\0'; i++)//reads each character until NULL
    {
        for(size_t j = 0; 
        {
            int a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = value(argv[3][i], j);
            //value is the function I made that takes the character and the j value into account
            *ptr = a[i][j] + '0';//did + '0' to make sure the int is converted into char
        }
    }

    if( (fwrite(ptr, sizeof(char), rate*strlen(argv[3])*length, filename)) != rate*strlen(argv[3])*length)
    {
        printf("\nWas not able to copy data to file.");
    }

    fclose(filename);

    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _My program isn't allocating memory_ Does that mean `Memory could not be allocated.` is being printed?

Comment: `data = malloc(sizeof(strlen(argv[2]) * length * rate * bytesper);` `length` is unitialized and `rate` and `bytesper` aren't defined.

Comment: @FiddlingBits yup I forgot that, assume those things are defined. I'll edit that in right now. They all have their own values.

Comment: @awb0000 `sizeof(strlen(argv[2])` Missing parenthesis aside, what's that supposed to mean? Please post the actual, compilable code.

Comment: @dxiv so basically the strlen(argv[2]) gets the amount of characters in the string argv[2]. So I'm multiplying that to length, rate, and bytes per character

Comment: @awb0000 `sizeof` ?

Comment: @dxiv I see where you are going... you're right there shouldn't be a sizeof there